# Extension method to convert SubSonic SqlQuery object to plain SQL

Tags: c#, sql, subsonic

I sometimes need to see what SQL statement SubSonic generates.

That works great with:

```
SqlQuery qry = DB.Select().From<Product>()
                 .Where(Products.Columns.Name).IsEqualTo("Productname");

Console.WriteLine(qry.BuildSqlStatement());
```

However that returns the query with parameters (`SELECT ... WHERE productname = ?productname`). So, I always have to find the real values in my code and replace the parameters with the propper formatted value (e.g. productname = 'Productname') which can be really annoying with complex querys.

So, I decided to make an extension method that I want to share (look at my answer for the code).

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Otherwise, I suggest you post your solution as an answer rather than part of this question (and make it community wiki perhaps) - it will probably get closed otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is far away from being perfect, but it fits my needs for now.

But I can use

```
 Console.WriteLine(qry.BuildSqlStatementDebug());
```

then copy the result to Clipboard and run it agains my DB from Query Browser.

```
using System;
using SubSonic;

namespace MyNamespace.ExtensionMethods
{

public static class SubsonicSqlQueryExtensionMethods
{

    public static String BuildSqlStatementDebug(this SqlQuery qry)
    {

        var result = qry.BuildSqlStatement();

        foreach (var c in qry.Constraints)
        {

            if (c.Comparison == Comparison.BetweenAnd)
            {
                result = result.Replace(c.ParameterName + "_start", GetFormattedValue(c.StartValue, c.DbType));
                result = result.Replace(c.ParameterName + "_end", GetFormattedValue(c.EndValue, c.DbType));
            }
            else
            {
                result = result.Replace(c.ParameterName, GetFormattedValue(c.ParameterValue, c.DbType));
            }

        }

        return result;

    }

    // Works for MySQL
    private static readonly String formatter_date = "'{0:yyyy-MM-dd}'";
    private static readonly String formatter_datetime = "'{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss}'";

    private static readonly String formatter_string = "'{0}'";

    private static String GetFormattedValue(Object value, System.Data.DbType type)
    {

        switch (type)
        {
            case System.Data.DbType.AnsiString:
                return String.Format(formatter_string, value);
            case System.Data.DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength:
                return String.Format(formatter_string, value);
            //case System.Data.DbType.Binary:
            //    break;
            case System.Data.DbType.Boolean:
                return (Boolean)value == true ? "true" : "false";
            //case System.Data.DbType.Byte:
            //    break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.Currency:
            //    break;
            case System.Data.DbType.Date:
                return String.Format(formatter_date, value); break;
            case System.Data.DbType.DateTime:
                return String.Format(formatter_datetime, value); break;
            case System.Data.DbType.DateTime2:
                return String.Format(formatter_datetime, value); break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.DateTimeOffset:
            //    break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.Decimal:
            //    break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.Double:
            //    break;
            case System.Data.DbType.Guid:
                return String.Format(formatter_string, value);
            //case System.Data.DbType.Int16:
            //    break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.Int32:
            //    break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.Int64:
            //    break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.Object:
            //    break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.SByte:
            //    break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.Single:
            //    break;
            case System.Data.DbType.String:
                return String.Format(formatter_string, value);
            case System.Data.DbType.StringFixedLength:
                return String.Format(formatter_string, value);
            //case System.Data.DbType.Time:
            //    break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.UInt16:
            //    break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.UInt32:
            //    break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.UInt64:
            //    break;
            //case System.Data.DbType.VarNumeric:
            //    break;
            case System.Data.DbType.Xml:
                return String.Format(formatter_string, value);
            default:
                return value.ToString();
        }

    }

}

}
```